# Carrierwave returns path of tmp file instead of actual in a callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, carrierwave

In an application I wanted to send public file URL to a service in an `after_create` callback. So, the code (simplified) looked like this:

```
class UserProfile < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :video, VideoUploader
  after_create :send_url_to_service

  private

  # Just logs the URL
  def send_url_to_service
    Rails.logger.info video.url
  end
end
```

To my frustration, after the upload, the `send_url_to_service` callback always logged the cached file path - something like `'uploads/tmp/1473900000-123-0001-0123/file.mp4'` instead of `'uploads/user_profiles/video/1/file.mp4'`. I tried to write a method to form the URL from the actual file path, but it did not work because the file wasn't there yet.

So, the question is, how do you obtain a final file URL in a situation like this?

*P. S. Please note, this is a self-answered question, I just wanted to share my experience.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution for me was to use the `after_commit ..., on: :create` callback instead of `after_create`:

```
class UserProfile < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :video, VideoUploader
  after_commit :send_url_to_service, on: :create

  private

  # Just logs the URL
  def send_url_to_service
    Rails.logger.info video.url
  end
end
```

The answer is pretty obvious, though I wasted a long time wandering around it. Explanation is simple: `after_commit` callback fires only after all information is successfully persisted. In my case the file was not yet persisted to storage directory (on `after_create` stage) - that is why I got the temporary file url instead of the actual one. Hope this helps somebody and saves their time.

Comment: Using rails 5.0.3 with CarrierWave v2.0.3, I still got the tmp path after change `after_create` to `after_commit`.

Comment: I also tried to call `reload` - but result is that file did not saved at all

Answer (score 0):

Using Rails 7.0.4 and carrierwave 2.0, using `after_commit :foo, on: :create` callback still returned tmp paths for me.

What worked was using [Carrierwave callbacks](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-use-callbacks), specifically `after :store, :foo` in the uploader class itself. This ensures that the call to fetch the file's URL only occurs after your file is uploaded to a cloud storage.

```
# app/uploaders/video_uploader.rb

class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  after :store, :foo

  def foo(_new_file)
    Rails.logger.info model.video.url
  end
end
```

Notes:

- The `foo` method requires an argument to work. In this case, an unused `_new_file` argument.
- The `model` variable points to the instance object the uploader is attached to.